# ¿Cómo dar click a un elemento creado dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, click

Tengo el siguiente código para añadir un botón y posteriormente darle click en JavaScript:

```js
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.className = 'js-btn-next';

if(btn.click()){
  console.log("Diste click!!");
}
else{
  console.log("Error dando click");
}
```

Pero como pueden notar no da click y devuelve el mensaje "Error dando click" que es la instrucción que le he dado en caso de que no se haga efectivo el click.

He intentado:

```
btn.click();
```

Que hasta donde sé es la única forma de dar click en JavaScript, agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el click funcione se debe agregar un callback al evento `onclick` del botón.

```js
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.className = 'js-btn-next';
btn.innerText = 'soy un botón'

// agregar un manejador para el evento click del botón
btn.onclick = () =>  console.log('diste click') 
// agregar el botón al documento
document.body.appendChild(btn)
```

Comment: Hola que tal amigo, gracias por tu respuesta, pero aún no funciona. Es que si te fijas el boton tiene una clase, tengo otra función que cuando se de click en ese botón haga otra acción, pero con tu respuesta solo salta una alerta, pero no se hace efectivo el click.

Comment: De acuerdo, ya actualicé la respuesta.